# swiftui bring view to center and blur background after long press like messages app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I can't seem to find how to bring a view to the center like a popup and blur background like when you long press a message in the messages app.

I know there is a simple native way to do this but I can't seem to find out how.

Comment: Peek and Pop are long deprecated. What you see in Messages is just a context menu, though they’re presenting some extra views with it. Context menus in SwiftUI are easy: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-a-context-menu

Comment: "I know there is a simple native way to do this" I do not think so, in that thing lots of code happening and it is custom made for messages app, apple would never share that code as API, but it is possible to make same thing in custom way.

Comment: I have come across the modifier .contextMenu which seems to work in a similar way.

Comment: As u said! contextMenu is one thing and the effect or animation on messages app is other thing, you put both them beside together and say they are the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63374675/how-to-blur-background-when-another-view-is-active?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`contextMenu(menuItems:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contextmenu(menuitems:)). It shows those buttons you see, and automatically blurs the background content to focus the selected view.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 30) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 20) { _ in
                    Text(String(Int.random(in: 1 ... 100000000)))
                        .padding()
                        .contextMenu {
                            Button {
                                //
                            } label: {
                                Label("Reply", systemImage: "arrowshape.turn.up.left")
                            }

                            Button {
                                //
                            } label: {
                                Label("Copy", systemImage: "doc.on.doc")
                            }

                            Button {
                                //
                            } label: {
                                Label("Translate", systemImage: "arrow.left.arrow.right")
                            }

                            Button {
                                //
                            } label: {
                                Label("More…", systemImage: "ellipsis.circle")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]